# What is better, "self study" or a "research internship"

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, independent-researcher, research-assistantship

I am a 4th year student in an bachelors in Electronics Engineering program in a university in India. I am plan to pursue a career as a researcher in Machine Learning and computer vision, and hence I applied to "Master's of Science in Computer Science" degrees for fall 2016 term to universities in the USA. Sadly couldn't get an admission.

I am preparing for the fall 2017 admissions, and trying to look for ways to to improve application.

Which is better plan ?

**1) Self study :**

I plan on studying a number of computer science, machine learning and computer vision courses on my own and simultaneously working on projects. I hope that I publish 1-2 technical/research papers during this period, that would improve my chances of admissions.

I personally prefer this option, since I do not have a very strong background (as compared to students that have majored in computer science), and I would like to solidify my background. I am very sure that I can do a substantial amount work by adapting this plan.

But, I am not very sure how much will this help in strengthening my application. I am also not very sure about how I present the self studying part (do I write a blog? Do I make youtube videos? how much do these matter?) in such a way as to influence the admission decision in my favour.

**2) Work in as a research intern**

This is a plan that a colleague of mine proposed, and also one that my father insists on. I look for a research internship in the US, and work as a research intern for 3-6 months. I hope to publish 1-2 research papers during this term, which will strengthen my application. It might also lead to better letters of recommendation.

Comment: If you could not get admission of masters degree, what made you think you can find research internship? If they have research internship slot, why don't they give it to their graduate students?

Comment: @scaaahu I didn't say I will apply for research internships only in the same universities I applied to. I would also apply to places where I think I have a chance of getting one.

Comment: If they have research internship slot, why don't they give it to their **own** graduate students? Computer Science research assistantship is not easy to get. In many cases, people get admissions (masters), but don't get  research assistantship. Most research assistantships are given to PhD students.

Comment: _work as a research intern for 3-6 months. I hope to publish 1-2 research papers during this term_ — You need to seriously adjust your expectations.  The chances of _anyone_ publishing 1–2 high-quality research papers in their first 3–6 months in _any_ field are vanishingly small, and by your own admission, you're starting with a relatively weak background.  (And publishing low-quality research papers will only hurt you.)